# After Anniversary update, Remote Desktop resolutions revert to too high a setting

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-10-v1607, high-dpi, high-resolution

I have a Dell XPS 13 with Windows 10 that I recently updated to 1607.  One of the major roles for this machine is to use Remote Desktop to access individual servers in my data center.  Previous to the upgrade, I had added PreferExternalManifest a key in HKLM/Software/CurrentVersion/SideBySide, set to 1, and then had an external manifest for the mstsc.exe.  Without this, when I used RDP to access servers, the resolution was so high as to make reading the remote session very hard.  Everything is tiny.  With the external manifest, I can see the remote sessions.

After the update, the key was gone.  I went to HKLM/Software/CurrentVersion/SideBySide and added the key, again.  The external manifest for MSTSC was still there.  After a reboot, I found that the MSTSC.exe would not start.  The desktop icon didn't work.  Running the command from a prompt didn't work.  No error reported.  I remove the key and reboot, and RDP works again, but I can't read the remote session.

I see that I can use the system menu and zoom the remote session, if I give up full screen.  I like full screen.  Do I have a choice of giving up full screen or a life of squinting?  Is there a way that I can have a full-screen RDP with a remote session resolution that I can see without squinting?

TIA

Comment: I have the same situation, this was working since the last Windows 10 update. Now if the key is set mstsc.exe silently fails to execute. So annoying

Comment: Not strictly an answer, but rolling back the update definitely works http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/since-windows-10-anniversary-update-remote-desktop/7b57aa3f-533a-4a5b-b545-0a2ac1cdf959